# How to pass JSONB array from python to postgres?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to insert JSONB array in postgres as below.

```
INSERT INTO student (studentRelations) VALUES ( 
array['{"relation":"father", "name":"ABC"}',
      '{"relation":"mother", "name":"XYZ"}']::jsonb[])
```

*"studentRelations"* column mentioned below is of type *JSONB[]*

Ex: studentRelations is an array of {relation, name}.
So, it contains an array of {"father", "father_name"}, {"mother", "mother_name"},  etc....

The above query works fine via postgres terminal but I would like to know how to pass it through python code.

Probably, I need to create a loop & assign the values for {relation, name} in above column.

Can anyone please suggest with syntax.

Comment: Why use `jsonb[]` at all? You are mixing types Postgres `array`  and `jsonb`. Use `jsonb` type and pass in a JSON array of objects. Assuming you are using `psycopg2` then you can use its [JSON adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json).

Comment: I'm not used to the PostgreSQL queries in Python but, if all that you want is a way to format a query string with dynamic values, you can `import json` and `relations = [{'relation': 'father', 'name': 'ABC'}, {'relation': 'mother', 'name': 'XYZ'}]` and use `f'INSERT INTO student (studentRelations) VALUES (array{json.dumps(relations)}::jsonb[])'` as your query string.

Comment: @accdias, except that is not what the OP wants. `json.dumps(relations)` yields `'[{"relation": "father", "name": "ABC"}, {"relation": "mother", "name": "XYZ"}]'` and `select array['[{"relation": "father", "name": "ABC"}, {"relation": "mother", "name":"XYZ"}]'
]::jsonb[];` yields `{"[{\"name\": \"ABC\", \"relation\": \"father\"}, {\"name\": \"XYZ\", \"relation\": \"mother\"}]"}`. *NOTE* it is `array[]` not `array{}`. What the OP is doing is creating a `jsonb[]` array of JSON objects.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the `{}` in the [`f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498)
 refers to the argument `{json.dumps(relations)}`, which will be expanded to the result of the expression inside it. If you test it, you will see the difference: `'INSERT INTO student (studentRelations) VALUES (array[{"relation": "father", "name": "ABC"}, {"relation": "mother", "name": "XYZ"}]::jsonb[])'` (even though I see it's still not exactly  what OP wants).

Comment: You should not be using `f` strings for passing in parameters, instead use proper [parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). In any case `json.dumps` is going to create a string that will not work with `array{json.dumps(relations)}::jsonb[]`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver : I am using pyscopg2 & am sure of the data format too as  I want to put array of key-value pairs :     

 [ {"relation":"father", "name":"ABC"}',
      '{"relation":"mother", "name":"XYZ"}']

I would appreciate if you can give a code example of how to use jsonb type and pass in a JSON array of objects into it.

Comment: The docs [JSON adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json) already do that.